# In Apache2 Error.log: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, flask, apache2, modulenotfounderror

Context:

- Ubuntu 20
- apache2
- python 3.8
- flask 2.0
- venv
- PyCharm

This works fine
**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


def func1():
    return "test1"


@app.route("/")
def index():
    f1 = func1()
    return f1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUJgw.png)

This doesn't work
**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
import mod

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    f1 = mod.func1()
    return f1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[works not 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A6aY.png)

mod.py

```
def func1():
    return "test1"
```

[works not 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVlzY.png)

In apache2 error.log

[apache2 error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq6aa.png)

In Browser

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcuSY.png)

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is due to the file system in Linux.This code would work perfectly in windows, But in Linux you should write.

```
import .mod
```

or

```
from ubc3 import mod
```

or

```
import ubc3.mod
```

Comment: Thank you Khushal. Solution 2 and 3 worked. Solution 1 (.mod) did not.